# How to distribute an AND operator in Coq?

Tags: coq

I have this hypothesis: `H : (x = s \/ x = t) /\ OoS v x`. My current goal is `OoS v s \/ OoS v t`. So, my idea to solve it was to distribute the AND operator in H to get `H : (x = s /\ OoS v x) \/ (x = t /\ OoS v x)`. And then I would transform this into: `H : (OoS v s \/ OoS v t`. And with `auto`, the proof would be done.

I searched for something useful with the command: `Search _ ((?a \/ ?b) /\ ?c -> (?a /\ ?c) \/ (?b /\ ?c)).`, but I found nothing.

I solved the proof with something else, but I would like to know if such a thing is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `decompose [and or] H; subst; auto` ?

You may also prove a distributivity lemma, then use `rewrite`s.

```
Lemma and_or_dist (P Q R: Prop): (P \/ Q) /\ R <-> (P /\ R \/ Q /\ R).
Proof. tauto. Qed. 

Require Import Setoid. 
Goal forall x v s t, (x = s \/ x = t) /\ Oo5 v x -> Oo5 v s \/ Oo5 v t.
intros x v s t H; rewrite and_or_dist in H. (* ... *)
```

Comment: I don’t how decompose and subst work, but it’s working. Thanks! Now, I need to understand how they work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approximation of a decomposition tactic :

```
Ltac decompose1 H :=
  let h1 := fresh "H1" in
  let h2 := fresh "H2" in 
  match type of H with
    ?A /\ ?B => destruct H as [h1 h2]; decompose1 h1; decompose1 h2
  | ?A \/ ?B => destruct H as [h1 | h2]; [decompose1 h1 | decompose1 h2]
  | False => destruct H
  | ~ ?A =>  destruct H
  | _ => idtac 
end.


Goal forall x v s t, (x = s \/ x = t) /\ Oo5 v x -> Oo5 v s \/ Oo5 v t.
intros x v s t H; decompose1 H. 
 subst ; auto. 
 subst; auto. 
Qed. 

Goal forall x v s , (x = s \/ x <> x) /\ Oo5 v x -> Oo5 v s .
intros ? ? ?  H; decompose1 H. 
subst; auto. 
trivial. 
Qed.
```